# Are there any online databases of kinship terms across languages?

Tags: cross-linguistic, reference-request, vocabulary, kinship-terms

Related to [a question at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/paucity-of-words-for-relationships), I am interested in doing a comparative analysis of kinship terms in various languages. What would help me with this is an inventory of terms for individual languages.

There are online explanations of different systems, but I haven't been able to find a list for many common languages (the main IE/Semitic/East Asian languages). Historical ones like Old English/Latin/PIE would be good, too.

Is there a reference that tabulates the terms for each language? If not that, at least one that lists comprehensively the kinship terms with their definition in English?

Comment: If you look for historical ones the there is a reverse word index here: http://www.palaeolexicon.com/ReverseIndex That means that you first find the common word in English and then you get the correspondences in different ancient languages. The list is ginormous but i am not sure it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you already seen this? http://www.austkin.net/

An excellent database

Also, have a look at https://ids.clld.org/chapters/2 (see Chapter 2, Kinship)

Comment: No, I hadn't seen that before, but yes, those are exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: @Mitch Here's a database for [Australian languages](http://austkin.pacific-credo.fr/)

Comment: Both those links are now unavailable. Do you have new links for them, and can you summarize in your answer what is there?

Comment: @Mitch I've updated the second link. Let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: @AlexB. Nice link! (for a whole bunch of stuff)

Comment: I notice the AustKin link is broken as well, here's the [new one](http://www.austkin.net)

Answer (score 8):

If you are interested in including kin terms of signed languages in your analysis, there is one such dissertation which examines kinship terms in ~40 signed languages. The author of this dissertation is Erin Wilkinson and the full citation is given below:

Wilkinson, E. L. (2009). [Typology of signed languages: Differentiation through kinship terminology](https://repository.unm.edu/handle/1928/9826). PhD thesis, University of New Mexico; Albuquerque, NM.